# OpenGL - Fill In Skateboarding Quarter Pipe

Tags: c, opengl

I am working on drawing a skateboarding quarter pipe in OpenGL and can't figure out the last step to filling it in.  I am still very new to OpenGL so this is probably just a trivial problem that I am overlooking.  Right now the code I have produces the following (don't mind the colors, we haven't covered textures yet in class)

[image]

and am using this function to draw the quarter pipe.

```
void draw_quarterpipe()
{
    // Quarterpipe Ramp
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    for (int i=-90; i <= 0; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(Cos(i), Sin(i)+1, -1);
        glVertex3f(Cos(i), Sin(i)+1, 1);
    }
    glEnd();


    // Coping
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f((Cos(i) * 0.025) + 1, (Sin(i) * 0.025) + 1, -1);
        glVertex3f((Cos(i) * 0.025) + 1, (Sin(i) * 0.025) + 1, 1);
    }
    glEnd();


    // Coping End Cap
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f((Cos(i) * 0.025) + 1, (Sin(i) * 0.025) + 1, 1);
    }
    glEnd();


    // Coping End Cap
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f((Cos(i) * 0.025) + 1, (Sin(i) * 0.025) + 1, -1);
    }
    glEnd();


    // Platform
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 0, -1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 1, 1);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 0, 1);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, -1);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 0, -1);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 1, -1);
    glVertex3f(1.5, 1, 1);
    glEnd();

}
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what the final step would be for filling in the space between the ramp and the platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.. :)

you can collect you alternate coordinated from you strip

```
// Quarterpipe Ramp
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
for (int i=-90; i <= 0; i++)
{
    glVertex3f(Cos(i), Sin(i)+1, -1);
    glVertex3f(Cos(i), Sin(i)+1, 1);
}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glColor3f(0, 1, 1);    
//( 1 ) Point from left bottom of the square as a centre (need correction of point)
   glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
//( 2 ) Coordinates of your triangle fan
   for (int i=-90; i <= 0; i++)
         glVertex3f(Cos(i), Sin(i)+1, 1);           
glEnd();
```

Reference image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try with `GL_POLYGON` [OpenGL primitives](https://taskercode.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/gl-primitives-with-background.png)

Comment: GL_POLYGON requires that it be a *concave* polygon. As you can see, what he's trying to draw is very much *convex*.